# What's the consensus on multiple C# (or other) tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, questions

I've been noticing lately that people are tagging with every version of the C# tag that exists (for example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6710631/transition-between-images-for-picturebox-in-c) is tagged [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23), [c#-4.0](/questions/tagged/c%23-4.0), [c#-3.0](/questions/tagged/c%23-3.0), and [c#-2.0](/questions/tagged/c%23-2.0)).  What is the best way to go about handling this?  I was thinking if there isn't a language specific question about it, it should be C#, but I wanted to make sure before I start editing...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If they have a reason to require backwards compatibility, they should tag it with the lowest common denominator (e.g. [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) and [c#-2.0](/questions/tagged/c%23-2.0) in this case).

In this instance I think the person just didn't know any better.